# How to redirect request with AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a migration path between an old an new API (different sub-domains) whereby we want to forward/redirect requests from the old during a transition period.

Canonical way of doing such things in AWS is by a [S3 redirection bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/tutorial-redirecting-dns-queries.html). Nice!

However, this does not support POST requests. From [WebsiteEndpoints AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html):

> Supports both object-level and bucket-level redirects. Supports only GET and HEAD requests on objects.

What are my other options? Spinning up a Lambda with a single endpoint, which returns the 302?

Comment: you should use `api-gateway`. the request being forwarded to lambda

Comment: Why is S3 involved? Can you handle it at the DNS level?